# React context not being updated within callback

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, pusher

I am subscribing a user to events using pusher-js, and am having an issue with the information I am passing in the callback not staying updated.  I use react router and have a 'location' context on my components.

```
connect() {
    let {pusher, channelName, eventName} = this.props;

    let pusher_channel = pusher.subscribe(channelName);

    pusher_channel.bind(eventName, () => console.log(this.context.location.pathname));
}
```

For demonstration purposes I am just console logging the current url pathname the user is on when the event comes through.  This component gets loaded and stays loaded when the user loads that application.  The problem is that, if a user navigates to another page in the app and an event comes in, the pathname does not reflect the actual page the user is on but rather the page the user was on when they initially loaded the app.

Is there a way to keep the callback updated as to any context or prop changes that have occurred?

Comment: Why not take pathname from router which you are using or simply `window.location.pathname`?

Comment: using window.location.pathname did work.  But can you explain why?  I was using location through context because react-router sets that...so (if I remember their documentation correctly) it was essentially the same.  Also, the react router documentation recommends going through them as opposed to going through window.location.

Answer (score 1):

### Updating Context

### Don't do it.

> React has an API to update context, but it is fundamentally broken and you should not use it.

[Read more](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#updating-context).

---

Use React Router's [location descriptors](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#to) instead.

Comment: I am not trying to update context.  I am just trying to view the context from within that callback.